# External memory data structure to replace vector of maps

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, data-structures, stl

I'm doing an iterative computation on a flow network during which I need to record how much each source contributes to the flow on each edge.  The flow on any one edge is due to 2% of the sources on average, so I define `vector< map<int, double> > flow`, where `flow[e][s] = f` means that the flow on edge `e` due to source `s` is `f`.  At each iteration, every `f` in `flow` gets updated.

The program's peak memory usage gets close to 4 GB.  This works on (32-bit) Linux and OS X, but it crashes on Windows (which seems to impose a [2 GB per process limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#memory_limits)).

How can I implement a disk-based data structure with a `vector< map<int, double> >` interface (or otherwise get around this problem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) for similar type scenarios. It might worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

If the vector of maps is what's consuming all of the memory, is it absolutely necessary to have `double` for the data fields? Changing might help.

Otherwise, you might be able to use a [memory map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_map), although making it cross-platform compatible will be a bit of work, especially with the embedded data structure you have for your mappings.